# How can I write a SQL script that shows if a record is related to other specific records?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
-- company
id  
1
2
3

-- company_partner
id  company_id  company_name
1   1           Nike
2   1           Reebok
3   2           Nike
4   3           Nike
```

I need a SQL script that shows if a `company` has a `company_partner` record. The output should be

```
company has_nike_partner  has_rebook_partner
1       true              true
2       true              false
3       true              false
```

I think I can use aggregation to see if there is a related partner but not sure how to access it in the SELECT statement

```sql
SELECT company_id, has_nike_partner, has_nike_partner
FROM company_partner
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN company_name = 'Nike' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND -- has_nike_partner ??
       COUNT(CASE WHEN company_name = 'Reebok' THEN 1 END) = 0;  -- has_rebook_partner ??
```

Comment: That's a kind of personal taste of course, but I think it's very strange to use count for that. I would prefer exists or an in clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your aggregated `CASE` expressions should be in the select clause:

```sql
SELECT
    c.id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN cp.company_name = 'Nike' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_nike_partner,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN cp.company_name = 'Reebok' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_reebok_partner
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN company_partner cp
    ON cp.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```